# Solving Piecewise Function where $f(x)$ is an involution

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $f(x) =
\begin{cases}
k(x) &\text{if }x>2, \\
2+(x-2)^2&\text{if }x\leq2.
\end{cases}$

Find the function $k(x)$ such that $f$ is its own inverse.

I know that $y=x$ is a function that is its own inverse. However, we have $2+(x-2)^2$ for $x\leq2$. I have found the inverse of $2+(x-2)^2$ to be $2+\sqrt{-2+x}$. When I graph this function, it looks like $k(x)$ in fact is $2+\sqrt{-2+x}$. I am not sure if $2+\sqrt{-2+x}$ is the correct answer though. Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your profile informs us that you've been here for three months.  Also, your rep reveals you're no longer a "new user".  And yet you clearly either haven't yet read the help section on "Asking" [e.g., how to ask a good question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), or you don't think it applies to you. Please include definitions of function, and inverse of a function, if it exists, in your post.  What does it mean for a function to be it's own inverse? Definitions are always a good place to start.  Please improve your post, as suggested.

Comment: Can this question be reopened? I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I'll try never to do this again. I think that this question has met the rules.

Comment: I appreciate your effort to edit the question, APiercingArrow.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

1. Note that all $x\leq 2$ have images in the range $[2,\infty)$
2. By using the relation $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ and Hint 1, you can find $k$